# Jsp&Hibernate paginition

Tags: javascript, jquery, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I have more than 3000 items stored in DB. I use hibernate code to retrieve 102 per time.

```
 public List<item> get102ItemsPerPageHibernateFunction(int pageNumber){
    criteria.setFirstResult((pageNumber-1)*102);
    criteria.setMaxResults(102);
    return criterial.list();
 }
```

There is a sturts2 function talking to the hibernate function and get the item list.

```
 public List<item> get102ItemsPerPageStruts2Function(int pageNumber){
        ItemDao dao = new ItemDaoImpl();
        List<item> itemList = dao.get102ItemsPerPageHibernateFunction(pageNumber);
        return itemList;
    }
```

What should I do in JSP to display the list I get. And how can I implement the view with a pagination navigation bar e.g. << 1 2 3 4 5...6 7 8 >>. Any examples? thanks.

The JSP code is below.

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="TheStruts2ClassListItemsByPageNumberAbove">
<%
    List<items> list = bean.get103ItemsPerPageStruts2Funciton(1)
    //a loop here to list out the item in list
%>
```

My current problems are: 1. a page navigation bar with dynamic page buttons 2. pass in page number in the JSP page.

Comment: How does your current jsp page look like without pagination code?

Comment: I can only list out the first 102 items in DB. I paste the JSP code above. please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try the <display:table> tag with the pageSize attribute as shown in this example - http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/02/dispaly-tag-pagination-sorting-example-JSP-servlet.html

Comment: I think I can. But the article here is more suitable for my situation here. http://mrbool.com/how-to-handle-pagination-using-jsp-pages/28345 thanks anyway.